# how to delete texture object under different thread with share qopenglcontext, on ubuntu20.04 with mesa driver

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have an class object called "ShowVideo", which inherits from QOpenGLWidget  and  QOpenGLFunctions.
In the  "initializeGL() " function,  i create a work thread and a sub renderer object, within the sub renderer object, i create a QOpenGLContext object, which calls setShareContext with the QOpenGLWidget context  for texture sharing.

under the "ShowVideo" class, there is a member function called "onSceneSwitch"(need to be called many times), in which i will first release all the sub renderer's  opengl resource (QOpenGLFramebufferObject, textures, etc)(by calling glDeleteTextures),  and then recreate the opengl resource (for example, using the glGenTextures).

on Windows system with nvidia graphic card, it works fine(the opengl resources is successfully released, the texture object name is ok for re-use after "glDeteleTextures",  even though the share opengl context not destroyed ).

however on ubuntu20.04  with mesa graphics driver, the  opengl resources can not be released .  (if i use glGenTextures to gen texture object, i would get new texture object id every time i call the "onSceneSwitch",  and thus results in quickly exceeding the "GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS")

The Code example is as follows:

```
class ShowVideo : public QOpenGLWidget,protected QOpenGLFunctions
{

protected:
    void initializeGL() 

{
    m_mainRendererContext = new QOpenGLContext();
    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
    format.setStencilBufferSize(8);
    format.setRedBufferSize(8);
    format.setBlueBufferSize(8);
    format.setGreenBufferSize(8);
    format.setAlphaBufferSize(8);
    format.setVersion(2, 0);
    format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
    m_mainRendererContext->setFormat(format);
    m_mainRendererContext->setShareContext(this->context());
    m_mainRendererContext->create();

    m_mainRenderThread = new QThread;
    m_mainRenderer = new MainRenderer();
    m_mainRenderer->moveToThread(m_mainRenderThread);

    m_mainRendererContext->moveToThread(m_mainRenderThread);
    m_mainRenderer->setGLContext(m_mainRendererContext);
}

    void onSceneSwitch()
{
    emit m_mainRenderer->releaseGLResourceSignal();

    ...

    emit m_mainRenderer->reCreateGLResourceSignal();
}

};




class MainRenderer : public QObject, protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
private:
    GLuint m_texUnit;
    QOpenGLFramebufferObject *m_Fbo = nullptr;

    QOpenGLContext *mContext;
    QOffscreenSurface *mSurface

public:

void setGLContext(QOpenGLContext *context)
{
    m_Context = context;
}

    void releaseGLResource()
{
    mContext->makeCurrent(mSurface);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &m_texUnit);
    delete m_Fbo;
    m_Fbo = 0;

}


void reCreateGLResource()
{
    mContext->makeCurrent(mSurface);
    glGenTextures(1, &m_texUnit);
    qDebug() << "the m_texUnit is : " << m_texUnit;
    m_Fbo = new QOpenGLFramebufferObject (size, format);
}

}
```

for example, if the "m_texUnit" is 3  on initialize after glGenTextures,  on windows system, i could get 3 after glGenTextures each time in the "onSceneSwitch";   but in  ubuntu system, because the two openGLcontext object is shared, the texture object name is unable to release.

By the way,  the reason i set the two openglContext shared, is that in the class "ShowVideo" member function  "paintGL", i use the texture id generated in  "MainRenderer"  for rendering.

Answer (score 0):

"if i use glGenTextures to gen texture object, i would get new texture object id every time" - as far as I know, this is correct behaviour of an OpenGL implementation.  It is not guaranteed that glGenTexture will ever return ids that were previously deleted. The correct way is to reuse texture objects rather than frequently create and destroy them (note that is texture is **not** equal to texture data; you can change what a texture contains at any time).

Btw, GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS is irrelevant here - it is not the number of textures you can create (this is only limited by technical stuff like sizeof(GLuint), available memory, or implementation-specific limitations), but the number of active *texture units* (see glActiveTexture), i.e. roughly the maximum number of textures that can be simultaneously used by a shader program.

Comment: Thanks. In my app,  sometimes i need to create many sub renderers at the same time,. And  in the "onSceneSwitch" function, i need to delete all the current sub renderers, then create new sub renderers,  so during the switch process,  the  glDeleteTextures  and  the  glGenTextures  would be called( include some QOpenGLFramebufferObject needing to delete and re-create).  .In my machine,  the  "GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS"  is  192.  so after  switching for a few times, the  result of glGenTextures would  exceed 192,  after that the  glActiveTexture would NOT be success.

Comment: @marswei You probably should restructure the code so that it reuses the renderers instead of recreating them. If that is not an option,  you could at least create some texture manager that implements texture reuse,  and use that instead of manual glGenTextures/glDeleteTextures. As for the glActiveTexture function, its parameter is ***not*** the texture id, but the *texture image unit*, which is ***unrelated*** to ids generated by glGenTextures. Please read https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture#Texture_image_units

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I am now  restructuring my  code for  texture reuse.    As for My previous code  working OK on  windows,  but  NOT  ok  on  ubuntu,   is it  because  that  the  opengl  implementation  is  different    between  windows drivers and  mesa  drivers?

Comment: @marswei To be honest,  given that you've used texture ids as parameters to glActiveTexture (the proper parameters are constants GL_TEXTURE0, GL_TEXYURE1, ...), it should have raised the  GL_INVALID_ENUM error,  and might have worked by a pure coincidence and luck (a common situation in OpenGL). But,  yes,  different implementations of OpenGL might have drastically different behaviour (e.g. with respect to failing on errors), even if still conforming to OpenGL specification.